# Why won't these alerts return in Javascript Google Maps API Geocode?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have the following function with which Geocodes an address and neither of the alerts within the results bit work! I have the exact same code on another instance of Geocoder on my page, and it works fine! Any clues?

```
function geocoderegion(addressX) {      
  alert("GeocodeRegion running for " + addressX);
  geocoder2.geocode({address: addressX, partialmatch: true }, function geocodeResult(results, status){
    if (status =='OK' && results.length >0) {
      alert("Geocode ran " + status);
      //return results[0].geometry.location;
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason:" + status)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: From where you are calling the geocoderegion method. I tested your code there is no issue and its working fine